# Are these two matrices equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am supposed to row reduce a matrix to reduced row echelon form. 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 4 & 8\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 4\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I have tried the following: 4 times row 2 - row 1 gives the following matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 & 8\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 4\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I checked the answer in the back of the textbook I am using and it says that the answer is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 & -8\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 4\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I see that this answer was obtained by using row 1 - 4 times row 2. Are both of these matrices equal? I thought that there could only be one unique matrix in reduced echelon form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that the reduced row echelon form of a matrix is unique. Using this fact and checking some arithmetic with your calculation should help you.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. I have gone over my arithmetic many times and it seems correct.

Comment: You are adding negative copies of row 2 to row 1 to clear out the 4 in row one. What effect does this row operation have on the rest of row 1?

Comment: That was what I observed according to the answer in the back of the book. What I originally did was take 4 times row 2 and subtract row 1, then replace row 1 with that. Doing so would give me a positive 8 and not negative.

Comment: Doing that would not lead to reduced row echelon form. I would suggest following the Gaussian elimination steps very carefully to get a good feel for basic matrix operations.

Comment: Could you explain why it would not lead to reduced row echelon form? The only difference between the matrices is a negative sign in front of the 8.

Comment: I think you are forgetting what happens to column 1 and column 2 of row 2 when you perform the operation that you stated previously.

Comment: Ohh I see my mistake now. I feel dumb :/